# What does "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed" actually mean?

Tags: scheduled-tasks

An example:
I have a scheduled task set to run at 11:00 with the option "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed" checked, but the computer doesn't start until 11:30. The task doesn't seem to start immediately, or at all.

1. Is there a limited time window after the official start time when the task can start?
2. Is there a delay before a delayed task gets re-triggered?
3. Where are the docs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation says this:

> If this setting is checked, the Task Scheduler service will start the task if the task was scheduled to run at a certain time, but for some reason (for example, the computer was turned off or the Task Scheduler service was busy) the task was not activated. The Task Scheduler service will not start the task immediately after the task was missed. By default the service waits ten minutes before starting the missed task.

Example
[documentation](https://forsenergy.com/en-us/taskscheduler/html/d758ff5d-27d3-4090-b1c2-14ecaa83ff12.htm).

Comment: Thanks! That link gives me a 404, but based on the cached version it has the information. I think it's only a mirror of the actual docs, unless forsenergy is Microsoft's unofficial website. :)

Comment: This text is quoted in many sources. It must have originated with some Microsoft engineer, but I didn't find the original text.

Comment: My hypothesis is that it was originally copied from Task Scheduler's help documentation. Clicking on help in Task Scheduler now just points to Microsoft's website.